# How to pass Form data variables to the rest api call from stand alone java code

Tags: java, rest, jira-rest-java-api

I got a situation to test the REST API's Delete call through Java code. I need to pass Form Data with 2 variables as below screenshot to the api request. someone please route me how to do that..

[image]

```
try {                       
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8999/testsource");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
                conn.setRequestProperty("session", "Cii2vEBZDplu5fI9JNXiM5");

                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }
                conn.disconnect();
                                
        } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but I'll make an attempt to answer it based on the assumption that your form data contains two fields which are:

- id
- permanentDelete

  ```
   String data = "id=the-id-goes-here&permanentDelete=yes-or-no-goes-here";
   byte[] bytesToSend = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
   outputStream.write(bytesToSend);
  ```

Comment: Hello @saaoc using the above code I have passed the request params but the values are not reading at REST end point level, I am getting only null values. I am using Restlet application as the REST service.